# Optimise SQL Query- sensor readings

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have two tables

```
Sensorlist
id (int, PK)
alias (varchar)

Readings
sensorid (int)
value (decimal)
date (datetime)
id (bigint, PK)
```

The readings table has an index on the id, the sensorid and on the date. This is in MYSQL, running on a raspberry pi.

And I want to get a list that shows each sensor in the list, with their most recent reading and their min and max readings in the last 24 hours.

I have the following two queries that I mush together into an array and display. I can't quite work out how to do the two as one query. The first query is very slow. How could I make it more efficient?

This takes 27 seconds to get the most recent readings:

```
select distinct s.alias, s.id, a.maxdate, r.value from sensorlist s
inner join
(
SELECT MAX(date) maxDate, sensorid FROM readings GROUP BY sensorid
) a on a.sensorid = s.id
inner join readings r on r.sensorid = s.id and r.date = a.maxdate 
ORDER BY s.alias
```

Query 2 gets the min/max values in the last 24 hours, this only takes 0.3 seconds:

```
select distinct s.alias, s.id, max(value) as maxval, min(value) as minval from sensorlist s
 inner join readings r on r.sensorid = s.id where r.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) group by r.sensorid
```

I assume that it is the way I have done the join to the subquery.. but I can't work out how to not use the subquery, or how to do the whole thing in one query (if that is a more efficient route?)

Thanks for any suggestions,
Charli

EDIT- the finished query (as given by the answer below, but MYSQL dislikes the word 'minvalue', added the indexes as per the answer)

```
SELECT sensorlist.id, sensorlist.alias, a.maxval, a.minval, b.value AS lastvalue, b.date as recentdate
  FROM (
          SELECT sensorid, MAX(value) AS maxval, MIN(value) AS minval
            FROM readings
           WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
           GROUP BY sensorid
       ) AS a
  JOIN (
select value, sensorid, date
FROM readings
JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(id) id FROM readings GROUP BY sensorid
) as m on m.id = readings.id
)
AS b ON a.sensorid = b.sensorid
  JOIN sensorlist ON sensorlist.id = a.sensorid
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the max and min readings from each sensor in the most recent 24 hours. Notice the absence of any `DISTINCT` instructions; the `GROUP BY` does that for you.

```
          SELECT sensorid, MAX(value) AS maxvalue, MIN(value) AS minvalue
            FROM readings
           WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
           GROUP BY sensorid
```

This query will most likely get a big performance boost if you create the following compound index on your `readings` table:  `(date,sensorid,value)`. That's called a *covering index,* and you can look it up on your fav search engine. It lets MySQL use random access to jump exactly to the right place in an index, and then scan that index sequentially looking for the information it needs. The whole query can be satisfied from that index.

Now, let's add the latest-measurement requirement.  The easiest way to find the latest measurement for each sensor is with this subquery. I'm assuming your PK, `readings.id`, is an autoincrement field.

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, sensorid  FROM sensors GROUP BY sensorid
```

That query gives you a list of `id` values in the `readings` table. These are the `id` values of the most recent readings for each distinct sensor. To optimize it, you can create another covering index on `(sensorid, id)`.

Now we can join that subquery into the rest of the query, and use those IDs to look up the latest values. Notice that we end up with two different subqueries. That's necessary because we need two different kinds of aggregates, aggregating on different criteria.  We'll also join up the sensor alias for display purposes.

```
SELECT sensorlist.id, sensorlist.alias, a.maxvalue, a.minvalue, b.value AS lastvalue
  FROM (
          SELECT sensorid, MAX(value) AS maxvalue, MIN(value) AS minvalue
            FROM readings
           WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
           GROUP BY sensorid
       ) AS a
  JOIN (
          SELECT value, sensorid
            FROM sensors
            JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(id) id FROM sensors GROUP BY sensorid
                 ) AS m ON sensors.id = m.id
       ) AS b ON a.sensorid = b.sensorid
  JOIN sensorlist ON sensorlist.id = a.sensorid
```

The trick to making this perform well is to optimize the two subqueries that hit your readings table, by using appropriate indexes.

Finally, you might test this query, which combines the two aggregator queries, to see if it's faster.

```
SELECT sensorlist.id, sensorlist.alias, a.maxvalue, a.minvalue, b.value AS lastvalue
  FROM (
          SELECT sensorid, MAX(value) AS maxvalue, MIN(value) AS minvalue,
                 MAX(id) AS maxid
            FROM readings
           WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
           GROUP BY sensorid
       ) AS a
  JOIN readings AS b on b.id = a.maxid
  JOIN sensorlist ON sensorlist.id = a.sensorid
```

Comment: Considerably faster would be an understatement, as it now runs in 0.134 seconds! Thanks!